# javascript split not working in IE9 - lower

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, split

I'm using IE 11 to emulate older versions of IE. The following code does not work as expected in **IE 9 and below**:

```
var search_input_val = $.trim($("#search_input").val()).replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
console.log(search_input_val);
var recBox_val_arr = search_input_val.split(/\s+/); // HERE
console.log(recBox_val_arr);
```

`recBox_val_arr` is logged to the console as `undefined`.

The above code returns an `Array` on IE 10 and 11, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari. Why is it not working in IE 9 and below?

### More details

Given this situation:

```
$("#search_input").val() === "ab abc";
search_input_val === "ab abc";
```

`recBox_val_arr` is logged as `undefined` by IE ≤ 9, `[object Array]` by Firefox and `["ab", "abc"]` by other browsers.

I'm linking to jQuery 1.10.2 via Google's CDN:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

I also tried `recBox_val_arr = search_input_val.split(' ')`, but `recBox_val_arr` is still logged as `undefined`.

Comment: Can you post the output of your console.log calls with a value that works in all other browsers?

Comment: What your input contains?

Comment: What version jQuery are you using?  Version 2.0 does not support < IE9

Comment: Split function only return array in any type of browser.please check your version for jquery js and your regex.

Comment: Guys check extra details and note. tnx

Comment: Give [this](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split) a read

Comment: This might sound a bit odd, but could you try something for me? Tell me what happens when you type `search_input_val.split(/\s+/)` directly into the console (no `console.log`). Alternatively, do the same but substitute `search_input_val` for the literal value.

Comment: @JordanGray found out that split does work and my prob is not this when i tried to call the index e.g. `recBox_val_arr[0]`. ie9 does support it but when you `console.log` the array it returns undefined which is btw really misleading.

Comment: Yep, I thought so. Want to know something *really* annoying? It works perfectly fine on an IE 9 VM—you get `LOG: test,test`! IE 11's emulation is pretty unreliable, I'm afraid. Want me to put this together into an answer?

Comment: yeah sure might help others go for it! what VM you using?

Comment: [Right here](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads). Definitely the best way to test in older versions! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### IE 11's implementation of IE 9's `console.log` is busted

There are indeed bugs with older IE's implementation of `split`, but that's not the problem here. In fact, `split` is working just fine—the real issue is IE 11's busted implementation of `console.log` when emulating IE 9:

```
console.log("test test".split(/\s+/)) // logs "undefined"
"test test".split(/\s+/)              // logs "[object Array]"
```

[image: Screenshot of IE 11 (emulating IE 9) console output for "test test".split, with and without a call to console.log]

### Like really, really busted

More generally, `console.log` in IE 11 emulating IE 9 doesn't support logging of objects or arrays:

```
console.log("foo");         // logs "foo"
console.log({ foo: "bar" }) // logs "undefined"
console.log(["foo"])        // logs "undefined"
```

[image: Screenshot of IE 11 (emulating IE 9) console.log output for a string, an array and an object]

### Even IE 9 wasn't this bad

Worst of all, this isn't even comparable with how IE 9 *actually* behaves. Here's what you get if you run IE 9 directly on a VM:

```
console.log("test test".split(/\s+/)) // logs "test,test"
```

[image: Screenshot of IE 9 console.log output for "test test".split(/\s+/)]

### Summary

- IE 11's emulation of IE 9 isn't perfect.
- `console.log` is totally borked when called on IE 11 emulating IE 9.
- Always use a VM ([freely available to download](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads)) for reliable cross-browser testing.

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function(){    
$("button").click(function(){
var search_input_val = $.trim($("#search_input").val()).replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
console.log(search_input_val);
var recBox_val_arr = search_input_val.split(/\s+/); //--Here--
console.log(recBox_val_arr);
console.log(recBox_val_arr[0]);
console.log(recBox_val_arr[1]);
console.log(recBox_val_arr[2]);
});
});
Create body with 
< body>
< input type="text" id="search_input" />
< button>Submit < /button>
< /body>

**console.log(recBox_val_arr);**

Input => hello 123 hi
Output => ["hello", "123", "hi"]

**Split function in PHP is used to break string into an array.**

console.log(recBox_val_arr[0]); == *hello* 
console.log(recBox_val_arr[1]); == *123* 
console.log(recBox_val_arr[2]); == *hi*

**If you put console.log() outside $("button").click(function(){}); then the value will be initially shown as "undefined".** 
Because it was not able to get value from text box.

Comment: your answer is waaaay off but checking the value of the array with the index did help. I found out that the array is there, ie9 just returns `undefined` when you console.log it. So anyway +1