# response.split(",")[0] not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I simply have:

```
<script>
    $('#blah').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: {"xxx":"yyy", "zzz":"nnn"}, // my variables...
            success: function(response){
                // response = "success,123" from server side
                // so for accessing to the values "success" and "123" I just:
                status = response.split(",")[0];
                count = response.split(",")[1];
                // now "status" and "count" are undefined in IE while it's working in all other browsers
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see in the above code, the server response to the Ajax is "success,123".

for accessing to values "success" and "123" I do:

```
status = response.split(",")[0];
count = response.split(",")[1];
```

Now `status` and `count` are undefined in `IE` while they are good in every other browsers.

What should I do to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395060/javascript-split-not-working-in-ie9-lower

Comment: try this: response.toString().split(",")[0];

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure why IE does this and I can't really test now, a smarter alternative would be to use JSON for response. If you use PHP, `json_encode` could be used to turn a simple array to JSON:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'count' => 123));
```

And then:

```
// your response originally looks like this:
// { status: 'success', count: 123 }

// you can define $.ajax with { dataType : 'JSON' } instead of:
response = $.parseJSON(response);
console.log(response.status);
console.log(response.count);
```

If you're not using PHP just search for the way to do it on your language.

This will also save you the headache of handling responses which contain your separator inside later on (sentences with `,` in them, for example)

Comment: @behz4d Don't forget to parse the JSON or define `dataType` in the `$.ajax` options to `JSON` before using this, I've updated the answer

Comment: And this also works on the rest of browsers such as FF, Chrome and Opera, but not IE! my IE version is 10.

Comment: `console.log` is broken in IE, especially when emulating IE9 with IE10/11, can you use another method to check the value? (like put it in a div or span, or use an alert box)

Comment: I'm using alert(), give me 2 mins I've got some progress

Comment: I got it to work but the solution seems funny, IE is much more dumber than I thought, see I was doing: `status = response.status` and then `alert(status)`, the alert value was empty in IE10 but working in every other browsers, I just did `alert(response.status)` and now the IE is working so in my `if`  situations I used `response.blah` instead of using another value.

Comment: Please update you answer regarding what I mentioned so I could accept it

Comment: I'm not sure what to change in the answer. I mention using the variable directly and not assigning it, what I left out is that IE is sometimes stupid with its implementation of console.log

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't defined the variables.Instead of:

`status = response.split(",")[0];`

I would try

`var status = response.split(",")[0];`